# xml file formatting in metro style app

Tags: xml, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

i want to write some data in XML file using metro style app (.Net Framework 4.5).

here is the code which i have written and it works fine but problem is that the whole string is being written in s single line instead of XML text formatting. Therefore i can't read it properly. Every time i need to reformat the newly added data to understand it properly.

Here is the code i have written :

```
    Dim f As New FolderPicker
    f.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
    f.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
    f.FileTypeFilter.Add("*")
    Dim folder As StorageFolder = Await f.PickSingleFolderAsync

    Dim rootEle As XmlElement

    Dim file As StorageFile = Nothing

    file = Await folder.CreateFileAsync("demoXML.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)

    rootEle = doc.CreateElement("files_tbl")
    doc.AppendChild(rootEle)

    Dim ele As XmlElement
    ele = doc.CreateElement("files")
    rootEle.AppendChild(ele)

    Dim otherEle As XmlElement
    otherEle = doc.CreateElement("field-1")
    otherEle.InnerText = "data-1"
    ele.AppendChild(otherEle)

    otherEle = doc.CreateElement("field-2")
    otherEle.InnerText = "data-2"
    ele.AppendChild(otherEle)

    Await doc.SaveToFileAsync(file)
```

if i want an output like this :

```
<files_tbl>
    <files>
        <field-1>data-1</field-1>
        <field-2>data-2</field-2>
    </files>
</files_tbl>
```

actually i want to use that xml file as my database as i don't want to store huge amount of data. I just need to store some properties of files such as file-names, extensions, location etc..

is it OK to use an xml file as a database ???

Answer (score 0):

You could consider changing your solution to use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`. That's newer and more user-friendly technology and it allows you format output when saved into a file or stream.

Check [`XDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) and [`XDocument.Save()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338419.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

To make it work with WinRT use [`OpenStreamForReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582102.aspx) and [`OpenStreamForWriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx) methods.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick reply.

it will be great if you could some links that explains the use of XDocument properly.

I have referred that msdn link you provided but couldn't get it...

Comment: OK, but you have to edit your question and show that XML you're trying to create.